# How do I solve terraform error subnet message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Hi  I get an error when trying to create a subnet.

Here is the error message:

```
Error: Error creating subnet: MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter cidrBlock
        status code: 400, request id: XXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Here is the snippet of the subnet code:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_az1a" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.example.id
  cidr_block        = "10.9.1XX.1XX/27"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
}
```

The vpc cidr range is 10.9.1XX.1XX/26

I have filled in the cidr block so why am I getting the same cidrBlock error?

Why am I getting the errors? 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you also creating a vpc in the same apply? Are you specifying the cidr_block for the vpc? It looks like you posted code block and the error are not related

Comment: What is the VPC cidr?

Comment: the vpc cidr range is 10.9.1xx.1xx/26